# DRF using another model field in a serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm moving my first steps with DRf and I'm having problems with this issue.
Suppose that I have a model made like this

```
class Snps(models.Model):
   snpid = models.AutoField(db_column='SNPID', primary_key=True)
   rsid = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
   chrom = models.CharField(max_length=5)
   pos = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'SNPs'

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.snpid)

class SnpsFunctionalelement(models.Model):
    snpid = models.ForeignKey(Snps, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SNPID', primary_key=True) 
    elementid = models.ForeignKey(Functionalelement, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ElementID')  
    celllineid = models.ForeignKey(Celllines, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CELLLINEID') 
    filetype = models.CharField(db_column='fileType', max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'SNPs_FunctionalElement'
        unique_together = (('snpid', 'elementid', 'celllineid', 'filetype'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(str(self.snpid) + str(self.elementid) + str(self.celllineid) + str(self.filetype))
```

Now in the `serializers.py` I want to get the field `rsid` from `Snps` and serializing it with the other fields replacing `snpid` of `SnpsFunctionalElement` and looking around i found this solution

```
class SnpsFunctionalelementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

rsid = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_rsid(self, obj):
    return obj.Snps.rsid
....
```

but it doesn't work saying that `'SnpsFunctionalelement' object has no attribute 'Snps'` and I can't understand what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ModelSerializer` class is extended, there is no need of any hassle. Simply indicate which model and what fields to use.

```
class SnpsFunctionalelementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Snps
        fields = ('rsid')
```

Comment: So in Meta i can specify different models and for each one their fields?

Comment: Each serializer for only one model. If you have several models, so you should make that many serializers. Basically, you cannot serialize 2 models in one serializers